# How to trigger an action when a site receives an email?

Tags: 7, emails

In Drupal 7, is it possible for users to send an email to a website, which will trigger an action?

For example, the user sends an email to offers@mydrupalsite.com. The Drupal site receives this and then sends the user an email with a PDF attachment.

I've searched extensively; however, the nature of the query means that it usually turns up relevant results.

Comment: There's a [pre-existing question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94182/email-processing-with-drupal) on this topic. There are some modules mention that get you the email receiving functionality, but the not the Rules event to complete your need.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Sorry, I ment to test it out and then got busy with other projects.

Comment: No need for sorry ... merci (thank you) for the (late) accept, and upvote, anyway! Next question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you might get it to work:

- Use [Mailhandler](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailhandler) to create nodes by eMail. The content of the node could be the actual content of the request as contained in the eMail.
- Use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to react to the event "after saving content" and combine it with the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module to send the eMail back to the user.

If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the 32 (!!!) great, and free, video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-the-rules-framework), organized in 7 chapters. For more details about the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module, refer to some interesting [Use Cases](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180149) detailed within its [Community Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180145).